# Getting batches in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

This question may have been asked but I failed to find it.
What is the simplest way to constantly get batches of data from a dataset? Is there a built-in tensorflow function to do so?
for instance:

`for i in num_trains:
    x_batch, y_batch = get_batch(x_train, y_train, batch_size)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:x_batch,y:y_batch})`

If there is not such a built in function, how would you implement it? I tried myself but I could not figure out how I can get a new batch different from the previous ones each time I call the function.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to prepare the dataset yourself (i.e., `x_batch`, `y_batch`) to feed into the model. So you can define a function which read from disk some data and return `x_batch` and `y_batch`.

Comment: @walkerlala I could not understand. Can you elaborate further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Feed batch data
def get_batch(inputX, inputY, batch_size):
   duration = len(inputX)
   for i in range(0,duration//batch_size):
     idx = i*batch_size
     yield inputX[idx:idx+batch_size], inputY[idx:idx+batch_size]
```

You can also use tensorflow's `dataset API` as well:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x, train_y))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

**Getting the batch:**

```
  X = np.arange(100)
  Y = X
 batch = get_batch(X, Y, 5)
 batch_x, batch_y = next(batch)
 print(batch_x, batch_y)
 #[0 1 2 3 4] [0 1 2 3 4]

 batch_x, batch_y = next(batch)
 print(batch_x, batch_y)
 #[5 6 7 8 9] [5 6 7 8 9]
```

Typically for running over the dataset for multiple `epochs`, you would do:

```
 for epoch in range(number of epoch):
    for step in range(size_of_dataset//batch_size):
        for x_batch, y_batch in get_batch(x_train, y_train, batch_size):
           sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:x_batch,y:y_batch})
```

**Using the `dataset API`:**

```
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
  dataset = dataset.batch(5)
  iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
  train_x, train_y = iterator.get_next()
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
   for i in range(2):
       print(sess.run([train_x, train_y]))
   #[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
   #[array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Comment: Hmm, I am having a hard time trying to understand it. Would this function give you a different batch everytime you call it ?

Comment: added details on how to use it.

Comment: In your dataset API example, if you would want to run the `train_step` you would have to convert `train_x` and `train_y` into tensors. Would this be a right way to do it: `train_x = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32,initial_value=sess.run(train_x))`? Would there be any problems when I feed this `train_x` into `feed_dict` later on? Thanks

Comment: Check: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays